# DB Design: additional info for many to many field

Tags: database-design, database-schema

Let's say I am making a blog using relational db

I have db table Posts, db table Tags and db table for many to many relationship between them.

```
Posts
    title
    author
    text

Tags
    tag_name

Posts_to_Tags
    post_id
    tag_id
```

But what if I need to add additional info to post's tags, for example if I want to save the name of a person who added each tag or time the tag was added, is this a good way to do it:

```
Posts_to_Tags
    post_id
    tag_id
    tagged_by
    time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can store data associated with the post-tag in the join table.

You may want to create a user/person table, and then have a foreign key to the primary key of the user table:

```
Users
    user_id
    name
    ...

Posts_to_Tags
    post_id
    tag_id
    user_id
    time
```